# 'Same' queries return different results

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two queries which are almost the same as below(the only difference is the r: in front of FOR in Query 1)

```
Query 1: MATCH p=()-[r:FOR]->() RETURN count(p)
Query 2: MATCH p=()-[FOR]->() RETURN count(p)
```

When I am running this queries against my Neo4j server, it returns different result. Query 1 is around 1/3 or query 2, I guess it is due to query 1 has 'combined' the results while query 2 didn't.(e.g. a-[FOR]->c and b-[FOR]->c were combined into 1 record), but just my guessing. I have tried to google or search in Neo4j documentation but no luck. Anyone can explain the difference?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MATCH p=()-[r:FOR]->() RETURN count(p)
```

This query binds the `FOR` relationship to the `r` variable (though it doesn't use it).

```
MATCH p=()-[FOR]->() RETURN count(p)
```

This query binds *any* relationship (i.e. of *any type*) to the `FOR` variable.

The correct syntax for specifying the relationship type in Cypher is `:XXX`, *with the leading colon*. The correct version of the second query would actually be:

```
MATCH p=()-[:FOR]->() RETURN count(p)
```